# Как называется такой тип корреляции?

Tags: анализ-данных, статистика, seaborn

Диаграмма рассеяния для двух переменных по Y - цена дома по X - среднее количество спален в дома:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется такой тип корреляции?

Comment: Корреляцией Пирсона. Вот только странную вы корреляцию ищите -  может все таки средняя цена от количества комнат?

Comment: Корреляция, кстати, слегка положительная. Но не сильная вообще.